mvn command fails with the error node_modules/nx: Command failed
I have the below GitHub Actions workflow that runs on a self-hosted Linux runner.
name: Dev-Release

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  registry_url: 'https://npm.pkg.github.com'

jobs:

  build-project:
    runs-on:
      group: myteam-UNIX
      labels: mybank

    steps:

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: List files
        run: |
          ls -al "${{ github.workspace }}"
          rm -rf "${{ github.workspace }}/*"

      - name: Set up Java 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'temurin'
          cache: 'maven'

      - name: Set up Maven
        uses: stCarolas/setup-maven@v4.5
        with:
          maven-version: 3.8.3

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '20.x'
          registry-url: ${{ env.registry_url }}
          always-auth: 'true'
          
      - name: Setup YARN
        uses: DerYeger/yarn-setup-action@master

      - name: Install Yarn dependencies
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: yarn install

      - name: Cache local Maven repository
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ~/.m2/repository
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('pom.xml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-maven-

      - name: Cache node_modules
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: '**/node_modules'
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nodemodules-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nodemodules-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
            ${{ runner.os }}-nodemodules-


      - name: Release with Maven ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          mvnVersion='3.9.8'
          export JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_HOME}"
          mavenHome="${{ github.workspace }}/apache-maven-${mvnVersion}"
          echo "mavenHome is $mavenHome"
          export MAVEN_HOME="${mavenHome}"
          echo $MAVEN_HOME
          mkdir "${{ github.workspace }}/jansitmp"
          cd "${{ github.workspace }}"
          echo "cd ${{ github.workspace }}"
          export MAVEN_OPTS="-Djansi.tmpdir=${{ github.workspace }}/jansitmp"
          mvn clean release:prepmyteam release:perform -e -U -B -P!build,release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

Strangely, when I set runs-on: ubuntu-latest the above workflow works fine without any errors.
However, when I run on my self-hosted Linux host mvn clean release:prepmyteam release:perform -e -U -B -P!build,release fails with the below error:
  export JAVA_HOME="${JAVA_HOME}"
  mavenHome="/www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/apache-maven-${mvnVersion}"
  echo "mavenHome is $mavenHome"
  export MAVEN_HOME="${mavenHome}"
  echo $MAVEN_HOME
  mkdir "/www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/jansitmp"
  cd "/www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal"
  echo "cd /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal"
  export MAVEN_OPTS="-Djansi.tmpdir=/www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/jansitmp"
  mvn clean release:prepmyteam release:perform -e -U -B -P!build,release
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    registry_url: https://npm.pkg.github.com
    JAVA_HOME: /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/_tool/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/11.0.24-8/x64
    JAVA_HOME_11_X64: /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/_tool/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/11.0.24-8/x64
    NPM_CONFIG_USERCONFIG: /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/_temp/.npmrc
    NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
mavenHome is /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/apache-maven-3.9.8
/www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/apache-maven-3.9.8
cd /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal
[INFO] Error stacktraces myteam turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Customer Portal                                                    [pom]
[INFO] Customer Portal - Core                                             [jar]
[INFO] Customer Portal - UI Frontend                                      [pom]
[INFO] Customer Portal - Repository Structure Package         [content-package]
[INFO] Customer Portal - UI apps                              [content-package]
[INFO] Customer Portal - UI content                           [content-package]
[INFO] Customer Portal - UI config                            [content-package]
[INFO] Customer Portal - All                                  [content-package]
[INFO] Customer Portal - Dispatcher                                       [pom]
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal >----------
[INFO] Building Customer Portal 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT                           [1/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal.core >-------
[INFO] Building Customer Portal - Core 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT                    [2/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.frontend >----
[INFO] Building Customer Portal - UI Frontend 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT             [3/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.frontend ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.apps.structure >--
[INFO] Building Customer Portal - Repository Structure Package 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT [4/9]
[INFO] --------------------------[ content-package ]---------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.apps.structure ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.apps >------
[INFO] Building Customer Portal - UI apps 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT                 [5/9]
[INFO] --------------------------[ content-package ]---------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.apps ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.content >----
[INFO] Building Customer Portal - UI content 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT              [6/9]
[INFO] --------------------------[ content-package ]---------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.content ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.config >-----
[INFO] Building Customer Portal - UI config 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT               [7/9]
[INFO] --------------------------[ content-package ]---------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.config ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal.all >--------
[INFO] Building Customer Portal - All 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT                     [8/9]
[INFO] --------------------------[ content-package ]---------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.all ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal.dispatcher >----
[INFO] Building Customer Portal - Dispatcher 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT              [9/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.dispatcher ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal >----------
[INFO] Building Customer Portal 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT                          [10/9]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepmyteam (default-cli) @ mybank-super-customer-portal ---
[INFO] Verifying that there myteam no local modifications...
[INFO]   ignoring changes on: **/pom.xml.releaseBackup, **/pom.xml.next, **/pom.xml.tag, **/pom.xml.branch, **/release.properties, **/pom.xml.backup
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal && git rev-parse --show-toplevel
[INFO] Working directory: /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal && git status --porcelain .
[INFO] Working directory: /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal
Warning:  Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? jansitmp/
Warning:  Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? mmc.adobecqms.net.cer
[INFO] Checking dependencies and plugins for snapshots ...
[INFO] Transforming 'Customer Portal'...
[INFO] Transforming 'Customer Portal - Core'...
[INFO] Transforming 'Customer Portal - UI Frontend'...
[INFO] Transforming 'Customer Portal - Repository Structure Package'...
[INFO] Transforming 'Customer Portal - UI apps'...
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO] Transforming 'Customer Portal - UI content'...
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO] Transforming 'Customer Portal - UI config'...
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO] Transforming 'Customer Portal - All'...
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO]   Ignoring artifact version update for expression ${project.version}
[INFO] Transforming 'Customer Portal - Dispatcher'...
[INFO] Not generating release POMs
[INFO] Executing goals 'clean install'...
[INFO] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal                                                    [pom]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - Core                                             [jar]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - UI Frontend                                      [pom]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - Repository Structure Package         [content-package]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - UI apps                              [content-package]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - UI content                           [content-package]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - UI config                            [content-package]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - All                                  [content-package]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - Dispatcher                                       [pom]
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] ---------< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal >----------
[INFO] [INFO] Building Customer Portal 1.0.54                                    [1/9]
[INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal ---
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ mybank-super-customer-portal ---
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ mybank-super-customer-portal ---
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/pom.xml to /home/u1225839/.m2/repository/com/mybank/au/portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/1.0.54/mybank-super-customer-portal-1.0.54.pom
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] -------< com.mybank.au.portal:mybank-super-customer-portal.core >-------
[INFO] [INFO] Building Customer Portal - Core 1.0.54                             [2/9]
[INFO] [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0:enforce (enforce-maven) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/core/src/main/resources
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] [INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/core/target/classes
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- bnd-maven-plugin:5.1.2:bnd-process (bnd-process) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
Warning: ARNING] /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/core/pom.xml [0:0]: Export-Package duplicate package name (com.mybank.au.portal.core.models) that uses the default version because no version is specified (1.0.54). Remove duplicate package or add an explicit version to it.
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/core/src/test/resources
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] [INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] [INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.1.2:jar (default-jar) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/core/target/mybank-super-customer-portal.core-1.0.54.jar
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- bnd-baseline-maven-plugin:5.1.2:baseline (baseline) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] [INFO] Downloading from adobe-public-releases: https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar (169 kB at 2.2 MB/s)
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ mybank-super-customer-portal.core ---
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/core/target/mybank-super-customer-portal.core-1.0.54.jar to /home/u1225839/.m2/repository/com/mybank/au/portal/mybank-super-customer-portal.core/1.0.54/mybank-super-customer-portal.core-1.0.54.jar
[INFO] [INFO] Installing /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/core/pom.xml to /home/u1225839/.m2/repository/com/mybank/au/portal/mybank-super-customer-portal.core/1.0.54/mybank-super-customer-portal.core-1.0.54.pom
[INFO] [INFO] [2/4] Fetching packages...
[INFO] [INFO] [3/4] Linking dependencies...
[INFO] [INFO] warning Workspaces can only be enabled in private projects.
[INFO] [INFO] [4/4] Building fresh packages...
[INFO] [INFO] error /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/ui.frontend/node_modules/nx: Command failed.
[INFO] [INFO] Exit code: 1
[INFO] [INFO] error /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/ui.frontend/node_modules/nx: Command failed.info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
[INFO] [INFO] Command: node ./bin/post-install
[INFO] [INFO] Arguments: 
[INFO] [INFO] Directory: /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/ui.frontend/node_modules/nx
[INFO] [INFO] Output:
[INFO] [INFO] /www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/ui.frontend/node_modules/nx/src/native/native-bindings.js:244
[INFO] [INFO]     throw loadError
[INFO] [INFO]     ^
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] Error: /tmp/nx-native-file-cache-4c936c5/19.1.1-nx.linux-x64-gnu.node: failed to map segment from shmyteamd object
[INFO] [INFO]     at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1465:18)
[INFO] [INFO]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
[INFO] [INFO]     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
[INFO] [INFO]     at Module._load (/www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/ui.frontend/node_modules/nx/src/native/index.js:60:27)
[INFO] [INFO]     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
[INFO] [INFO]     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
[INFO] [INFO]     at Object.<anonymous> (/www/git-runners/githubrunner-a5/_work/mybank-super-customer-portal/mybank-super-customer-portal/ui.frontend/node_modules/nx/src/native/native-bindings.js:184:31)
[INFO] [INFO]     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
[INFO] [INFO]     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
[INFO] [INFO]     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32) {
[INFO] [INFO]   code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
[INFO] [INFO] }
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] Node.js v20.12.2
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Reactor Summary for Customer Portal 1.0.54:
[INFO] [INFO] 
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal .................................... SUCCESS [  0.178 s]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - Core ............................. SUCCESS [  2.495 s]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - UI Frontend ...................... FAILURE [ 33.908 s]
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - Repository Structure Package ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - UI apps .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - UI content ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - UI config ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - All .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] Customer Portal - Dispatcher ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time:  37.393 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-05T17:11:35-05:00
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.15.0:yarn (yarn install) on project mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.frontend: Failed to run task: 'yarn install' failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
Error: [ERROR] 
Error: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Error: [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error: [ERROR] 
Error: [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Error: [ERROR] 
Error: [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
Error: [ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :mybank-super-customer-portal.ui.frontend
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for Customer Portal 1.0.54-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Customer Portal .................................... FAILURE [ 38.602 s]
[INFO] Customer Portal - Core ............................. SUCCESS [  0.004 s]
[INFO] Customer Portal - UI Frontend ...................... SUCCESS [  0.005 s]
[INFO] Customer Portal - Repository Structure Package ..... SUCCESS [  0.014 s]
[INFO] Customer Portal - UI apps .......................... SUCCESS [  0.013 s]
[INFO] Customer Portal - UI content ....................... SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] Customer Portal - UI config ........................ SUCCESS [  0.002 s]
[INFO] Customer Portal - All .............................. SUCCESS [  0.001 s]
[INFO] Customer Portal - Dispatcher ....................... SUCCESS [  0.001 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  39.508 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-09-05T17:11:35-05:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepmyteam (default-cli) on project mybank-super-customer-portal: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1' -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepmyteam (default-cli) on project mybank-super-customer-portal: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepmyteamReleaseMojo.prepmyteamRelease (PrepmyteamReleaseMojo.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:972)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shmyteamd.release.ReleaseExecutionException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shmyteamd.release.phase.AbstractRunGoalsPhase.execute (AbstractRunGoalsPhase.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shmyteamd.release.exec.MavenExecutorException: Maven execution failed, exit code: '1'
    at org.apache.maven.shmyteamd.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor.executeGoals (InvokerMavenExecutor.java:433)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Error:  
Error:  Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Error:  
Error:  For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Error:  [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Is there any workaround in order to resolve this error?

Does your runner have enough memory? Is it a persistent runner? Perhaps, try a fresh runner to make sure the build is clean.

@DeltaGeorge we could have memory issue but can u give me pointers of exactly what / where is responsible for memory issue? The runners are persistent. As u see we are using runner group comprising of 20+ runners so it chooses different runners everytime. However, the error is persistent for self hosted runner.

I tried the df -h command during the entire run until failure and did not find any mount space touching 100%

It would be good to try a clean runner to eliminate issues of persistence. GitHub hosted runners are ephemeral.

@DeltaGeorge this may not have to do with the github runner. Reason is that I exited the workflow mid-execution. Then logged on to the checkout github runner server host and ran the mvn clean command manually.
Running the command manually gives the same error as reported in the original thread.
